# Nullstellensatz for non-algebraically closed fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the Nullstellensatz holds for non algebraically closed fields, when the variety is taken over the algebraic closure. Let $R=K[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $\overline{K}$ the algebraic closure of $K$. I was able to prove that $\sqrt{I}\subseteq \mathcal{I}_R(\mathcal{V}_{\overline{K}^n}(I))$ for any ideal $I$. I'm struggling a bit with the other direction. My attempt goes as follows:

It is clear that given any ideal $J$, $V_{K^n}(J)\subseteq  \mathcal{V}_{\overline{K}^n}(J)$. Applying $\mathcal{I}_{\overline{K}^n}$ reverses the order, so we have:
$$\mathcal{I}_{\overline{K}^n}(V_{K^n}(J))\supseteq  \mathcal{I}_{\overline{K}^n}(\mathcal{V}_{\overline{K}^n}(J))=\sqrt{I}$$
where the equality is just the normal Nullstellensatz. I don't know if this idea seems fruitful since I haven't been able to get the reverse inclusion. Any ideas on how to show this direction would he highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

This result appears in Section 11.2.1 of [my commutative algebra notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf) under the name **Semirational Nullstellensatz** (which is not standard, but seems broadly reasonable).  The proof is indeed nontrivial.  (It uses something that I call **Lang's Lemma**.)  Perhaps there is a more straightforward approach -- indeed, the exercise at the end of the section seem to ask about this -- and if so I would be interested to know.

Comment: It seems like a nice proof. There is a typo on lemma 11.6 (it should be a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$. I don't see how you used 11.7 in the proof of 11.8. Could you expand a little bit on that? Thanks!

Comment: These are quite interesting notes on various kinds of Nullstellensätze! But there are some typos and (as I can tell so far, only minor) issues. Is this the latest version of the notes? And, in the proof of theorem 11.19, why is $V^a(I_0) = \mathbf{F}^n_q$ and not an extension of that?

Comment: @Bubaya: I just replaced the file with a more recent version.  Nowadays I find deducing the Finite Field Nullstellensatz from the Semirational Nullstellensatz to be overly elaborate.  My preferred take on FFN is given in http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/finitesatz_final.pdf.

Comment: Also, in any field $k \supseteq \mathbb{F_q}$, the vanishing locus of the ideal $I_0$ consists of $(x_1,...,x_n) \in k^n$ such that $x_i^q = x_i$ for all $i$.  But a nonzero element $x$ such that $x^q = x$ satisfies $x^{q-1} = 1$.  Since the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ give $q-1$ solutions, these are all the solutions in any extension field.

Comment: Thank you a lot, also for the explanation.